# Upgrading openssh-server on XenServer 6.2

Tags: ssh, xen

I have XenServer 6.2 which only has version:

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

I tried to upgrade it using:

```
yum -y reinstall opnssh-server
```

or

```
yum -y install opnssh-server
```

But I just get this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
citrix                                                   |  951 B     00:00
Installed package openssh-server-4.3p2-72.el5_7.5.i386 not available.
Nothing to do
```

Does anyone know how to upgrade it?

Comment: Why you want to change this?

Comment: 1. It has the heart bleed vulnerability 2. The newer version handles the 'Match' command in the config

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 is not affected by heartbleed.

Comment: I was led to believe that any version built before April this year was affected ... But also I need the 'Match' command to work

Comment: FYI- even if your OpenSSL version were vulnerable, ssh doesn't use TLS and as such, is not vulnerable to heartbleed.

Comment: Okie dokie ... So back to the question anyways, is there a way to upgrade it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to enable the CentOS repository.

By default, XenServer only enables the Citrix repository.

There are two ways to do this: permanently and temporarily.

I've [blogged about this in some detail](http://pandu.poluan.info/blog/20131106-20/howto-install-centos-packages-xenserver-dom0/), so I'll just cut to the chase and give the recommended way, i.e., the temporary way:

```
yum --enablerepo=base --disablerepo=citrix ...
```

Comment: Awesome, I read through your blog, and it sounds promising. I'll try it tomorrow, and if it does make my server go tits up, it's not too much to worry about cos it's just my testing server. Watch this space ...